# How render a value for input field in expressJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am learning ExpressJS and bootstrapped an application.
In a simple login application I am trying to render value of email address already entered by customer with incorrect password.
So when user enters correct email and wrong password for signing in they see error password incorrect but I want to fill email address field.
Here is the code

https://github.com/bradtraversy/node_passport_login/blob/master/config/passport.js#L25

```
  } else {
        console.log(email)
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
      }
```

it is printing correct email but I need to render it here

https://github.com/bradtraversy/node_passport_login/blob/master/views/login.ejs#L14

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate the [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#value) attribute of the email field

You should have something like that if you provide a `email` parameter to your template :

```
<input
 type="email"
 id="email"
 name="email"
 class="form-control"
 placeholder="Enter Email"
 <%= !email ? '' : "value="+email %> 
/>
```

Comment: You need to provide that `email` value to your EJS template. Could you show me the code where you do that ?